I am trying to increase the JavaScript heap memory for my angular application which is causing the app to crash
I am working on an ecommerce application that is multilayered using angular for its frontend. When I serve the application using ng serve the application is served to my local host but later on it crashes and displays a JS out of memory error and it exits.
I tried increasing the heap memory in my local angular and global angular using --max-old-space-size=4096 in both Packages.json file in my root folder and Windows terminal, but I am still getting this error:


Are you sure you don't have something that causes angular change detection to run over and over until it crashes? Not assuming there is, but could perhaps be something like that. E.g calling a function in template can cause this. Just throwing it out there if you didn't think of checking that? :)

does same happen if you turn off SSR?

Try setting up heap memory size to 8192.
PS: Might not be related but try and delete cache of your angular build from .angular to free up space. It can take space in GBs.

step:1 => Open your cmd by Run as administrator
step:2 => go to your project path and run Set NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=16384"
step:3 => run project ng serve
